# Expandable table rows in angular 4 with angular material for dynamic data(not constant data)

Tags: angular

Expandable table rows in angular 4 with angular material for dynamic data(not constant data). I need to get the data from API call and display some records.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.
Looks like it’s successfully changing to “dummy” since it’s making a (unsuccessful) call to retrieve it. What would be helpful is if you could boil the code down to a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (you can use Stack Snippets to do so).

Comment: see if jqxTreeGrid meets your requirements - https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-treegrid/